# I dont receive the arrays I want, can someone help me?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to make a program with 4 functions. 3 of them have to be the 3 coordinates x, y, z and the other one have to be the function, which give the np.array with all the coordinates together, but I only receive one giant array with all the factors of each one like an only element of the array. I don't know if I'm explaining myself, but here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def x(t):
   x = (5.25 * t)
return x


def y(t):
    y = (-0.365 * (t**2)) + (7.15 * t) + 34
return y


def z(t):
    z = (-0.49 * (t**2)) + (9.9 * t)
return z


def f(t):
    f = np.array([x(t), y(t), z(t)])
return f

f(t) [0:49]
t = np.arange(0, 21, 0.4275996114)
M = f(t)
print(M)
```

I have to print the first 50 coordinates of the ball until the time 20 seconds, but I receive the 50 numbers of x like only 1 element of an array.

Comment: firstly remove that " f(t) [0:49]" line and Can you explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Ok, I think I didnt explain my self. I have to do a program with 4 functions. the x,y,z are the coordinates functions of a ball, which a person kick. the starting coordinates are 0,34,0 and after that I need to use this functions to calculate the other coordinates in base of time. My program has to give 50 arrays with coordinates of the ball between the time 0 seconds and 20 seconds. I dont know if this time I expleined it better

Answer (score 0):

The question was not very clear but I think I understood your problem and what you are asking. Basically you want to get a matrix M in which each row is a numpy array containing the three x,y,z coordinates. You want to have as many rows as there are measurements in 20 seconds.

```
M = np.empty((0,3), float)
t = np.arange(0, 21, 0.4275996114)
for time in t:
    M = np.append(M, [f(time)], axis = 0)
print(M)
```

**Explanation**

First, we create what will become our matrix by specifying that each row consists of 3 columns. We want it to contain decimal numbers, so we specify float as type:

```
M = np.empty((0,3), float)
```

Then a problem you have in your code is that you only call the f function once, passing the entire t array of times as an argument. You actually have to call the f function once for each instant of time contained in t.
To solve it you have to make a loop on each element in t. The result of each call to `f()` must be added as a row in the M matrix.

```
t = np.arange(0, 21, 0.4275996114)
for time in t:
    M = np.append(M, [f(time)], axis = 0)
```

**Partial Output**

This output shows only the result of the range from 0 to 3. is just an example to show you the format of the output obtained

```
[[ 0.         34.          0.        ]
 [ 2.24489796 36.9906001   4.14364385]
 [ 4.48979592 39.84772596  8.10810311]
 [ 6.73469388 42.57137757 11.89337776]
 [ 8.97959184 45.16155495 15.49946782]
 [11.2244898  47.61825808 18.92637328]
 [13.46938776 49.94148697 22.17409413]
 [15.71428572 52.13124162 25.24263039]]
```

Comment: @AntalOppenheimer does this answer to your question?